# How to split a wstring

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a `wstring` variable and I want to split it by space character and put in a `vector`

```
wstring wStr = L"Hello World !";


vector<wstring> vw;

wstring st = L"";
for (int i = 0; i < wStr.length(); i++) {

    if (&wStr[i] == L" ") {
        vw.push_back(st);
    }
    else{
        st += wStr[i];
    }

}
```

My result should be like this in `vector`:

> Hello 
>  World 
>  !

But it doesn't go in if statement

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you are comparing two *pointers*. And those two pointer will never be the same. Instead compare *characters*:

```
if (wStr[i] == L' ') ...
```

---

On a related note, this is not the simplest way to split a string on space. Try this instead:

```
std::wistringstream wis(wStr);
std::vector<std::wstring> wv(std::istream_iterator<std::wstring, wchar_t>(wis), {});
```

Answer (score 3):

`wStr[i]` is the `i`th character of the buffer that `wStr` contains.

`&wStr[i]` is the memory address of that character.

`&wStr[i] == L" "` compares the memory address of the `i`th character in the buffer of the string object, with the memory address of the string literal.

Since the string literal is not the buffer of the string object, nor within the buffer, the equality comparison is never true.

Perhaps you intended to compare the value of the character instead: `wStr[i] == L' '`.

Answer (score -1):

I write one that works for `wstring` tokenizer length more than 1:

```
std::vector<std::wstring> splitString(std::wstring w, std::wstring tokenizerStr) {

    std::vector<std::wstring> result;
    long tokeninzerLength = tokenizerStr.length();
    long position = 0;
    long findIndex = w.find(tokenizerStr, position);

    while (findIndex != -1)
    {
        wstring str = w.substr(position, findIndex - position);
        result.push_back(str);
        position = findIndex + tokeninzerLength;
        findIndex = w.find(tokenizerStr, position);
    }

    result.push_back(w.substr(position, w.length() - position));

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tokenizing strings of length > 1 can be trivially done using `string::find` operations -- I'm not sure why you're introducing the unnecessary storage of several `std::vector<wchar_t>` objects. This implementation is actually much more costly due to repeat `push_back`s without reserving (resulting in multiple reallocations depending on string size), and also because vectors don't have an SBO.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance, I'm beginner at C++, after reading your comment I learn a lot, then remember `wstring` is like `wchar_t` array and has `length()` and can use index, so I don't need to save it to another `vector`. and Thanks for sharing the `find()` skill, I'm not familiar with `wstring` and not sure it can use  `substr()` and `find()`, after test it works, and I update a new version apply `find()` to split string. In my test case the new version use `find()` is 12 times faster than previous version, it's very useful.